# Как сделать редирект домена с тире?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть основной домен `http://www.test-site.com` и я хочу сделать редирект c

```
http://test-site.com
https://test-site.com
https://www.test-site.com
```

на него! Есть код редиректа который на других сайтах работает нормально, а на домене с тире вызывает циклический редирект! Подскажите как сделать что бы редирект сработал?
КОД

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test-site\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.test-site\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо экранировать -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\-site\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.test-site.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Развёрнуто

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\-site\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.test-site.com/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\-site\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.test-site.com/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\-site\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.test-site.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Добавил ваш код, но все равно циклический редирект

Comment: Кэш желательно почистить или с другого браузера попробовать. Ошибки в перенаправлениях нет.